# Odd Safari Video "Load" Behavior

Tags: javascript, safari, load, video-player

I wrote a simple video player for one page of my site that works by clicking buttons to change the `src` attribute of the source tags, then calling a load on the player element. The video element looks like this:

```
<video id="player" title="Video 1" controls  width="600" height="480" preload="metadata">
    <source src="videos/english.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="videos/english.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="videos/english.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="plugins/flash/player.swf" width="600" height="480">
        <param name="movie" value="plugins/flash/player.swf" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="file=../../videos/english.mp4" />
        <p>Your browser can't play HTML5 video. <a href="videos/english.webm">Download it</a> instead.</p>
    </object>
</video>
```

And the script relevant to the click event looks like this:

```
$(".playerControl").live("click tap",function(){

    // If the player isn't playing this divs video

    if($("#player").data('currentVideo') != $(this).data('videoID')){

        // Swap active button states

        $(".playerControl.active").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        // Pause the current video and swap the content, then load the player

        $("#player")[0].pause();
        $("#player").html($(this).data('innerHTML'));
        $("#player").data({
            innerHTML: $(this).data('innerHTML'),
            currentVideo: $(this).data('videoID')
        });
        $("#player")[0].load();
        updateBackup();

    }       
});
```

This works perfectly fine on Chrome and presumably Firefox, but the oddest issue comes up when I use this on Safari. The first video will show up, but every second video I attempt to play does not even try to load. Calling `load` on the player from the console does not yield results either, but an inspection of the player shows that its sources are correct, and the video will play if I manage to click it after a video that isn't working.

I do hope that doesn't sound too confusing, basically safari doesn't load every other video I try to play, but has no trouble playing any of the files on their own. I have a feeling there is some extra function that I have to call to get it to work, but I am not sure.

Update: I rewrote the click event to execute regardless of which button is clicked, and it is an issue with loading the video every other click, not with the video itself.

Update 2: I tried adding a couple lines that cleared the video html and loaded before inserting the new html, to initialize it, and that caused it to start loading about two-thirds of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to wrap `<video>` tag in a block and rewrite its innerHTML.

Something like this:

```
<div id="player-holder">
    <video id="player">...</video>
</div>

// rebuild player data and reload HTML.
$("#player").html($(this).data('innerHTML'));
$('#player-holder').html($('#player-holder').html())
```

This will rebuild `<video>` element and might help with problem in Safari.

Comment: The solution I ended up implementing was ditching the <source> tags and using "canPlayType(type)" to load in the proper format as the src directly. It seems <source> tags are not completely supported yet.

Comment: You can add your own answer also ;) It seems your answer for this question is more accurate for Safari.